# how to make a xaml control with different view modes

Tags: templates, xaml, conditional-statements

I'm trying to learn how to separate a view from its associated viewmodel, while making the view have as little or no code-behind as possible.

my control has a textblock when the object is in a display mode, and a textbox when the user wants to edit that field.  In both cases, these controls must bind to the same string in the modelview, but only the appropriate one should be displayed depending on the state of the viewmodel.  Previously, I'd just modify the panels child to a new element in the codebehind... but as I understand it, I should be trying to make all my changes in XAML for the view.

My viewmodel has a bool denoting if its in display or edit mode.  Is there a way to specify use of a different template depending on the value of that bool, but keep it all in XAML?

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? 

Put simply, the guideline to "make all changes in XAML" may not make sense for you. I'll provide a code sample, but if it looks more convoluted or less maintainable than something you completely understand, then you're doing yourself a disservice.

Comment: I'm still relatively new to WPF, and am getting used to what might be considered "best practices"... I watched a tutorial showing the MVVM pattern in WPF, and part of what came out of it was that the code behind should be nearly stripped bare... that if you are doing it right, your View should be almost completely XAML, and your ViewModel should be decoupled from view code... so basically I'm exploring different ways to put together an interface that might change based on user input.

Comment: I know that's what they're saying. However, every consultant I've met who puts these things into actual practice reports agnosticism on the idea. In my opinion, it was developed to facilitate the sale of Expression Blend to hybrid designer/developer teams in very large organizations.

Maybe the practice is best for team-based silo-projects in those kinds of places. But for line-of-business apps, it can be a massive distraction. 

I will give it this much, though: you will learn complex XAML markup. But don't believe for a second that if it's XAML, it's not code. It's all code.

Comment: OK, I've completed a working sample for you, in the answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to do what you say you're working on, by using DataTriggers.

First, define a `Style` which contains the `DataTrigger`s you want to use. For example, note here two identical styles for a `ContentControl`, each with a `DataTrigger` pair that performs the opposite of the other:

```
<Window.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" x:Key="HiddenWhenFalse" >
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger  Value="False" Binding="{Binding MyBooleanValue}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger  Value="True" Binding="{Binding MyBooleanValue}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" x:Key="HiddenWhenTrue" >
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger  Value="True" Binding="{Binding MyBooleanValue}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger  Value="False" Binding="{Binding MyBooleanValue}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then, in your main visual tree you would define `ContentControl`s which use those `Style`s, and assign the `DataContext` of the `Window` or `UserControl` or whatever to your ViewModel. Something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel >
        <Button Content="False" Name="Button2"></Button>
        <Button Content="True" Name="Button1"></Button>
        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource HiddenWhenFalse}">
            <ContentControl.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="ITS ALL TRUE"/>
            </ContentControl.Content>
        </ContentControl>
        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource HiddenWhenTrue}">
            <ContentControl.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="ITS ALL FALSE"/>
            </ContentControl.Content>
        </ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here is the ViewModel I'm using, note the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MainWindowViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Private _MyBooleanValue = False
    Public Property MyBooleanValue
        Get
            Return _MyBooleanValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            _MyBooleanValue = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(Nothing))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
```

Now, for the purposes of this sample, I simply wired up the two buttons to set the ViewModel value. If you want to use Commanding to wire up buttons, that's an entirely different topic. It's worth discussing, but for the sake of simplicity:

```
Class MainWindow 
    Private vm As New MainWindowViewModel
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        vm.MyBooleanValue = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        vm.MyBooleanValue = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        Me.DataContext = vm
    End Sub
End Class
```

Bear in mind that this sample explicitly styles a `ContentControl`, and that you'll have to change the TargetType of your style if you're working with a type that isn't descended from that class.